# Add comments programmatically to Visio file when all pages in source file contains comments

Tags: c#, comments, visio, aspose

Hello programming world,

I'm facing an issue, a blocker, and I tend to believe that my problem is a bug of Aspose.

I'm using Aspose library in order to work easily with Visio files. There is a file that has 2 pages and each page has comments. Now, my problem occurs when new comments are added to any of the pages.

**Error message**: *"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '/visio/comments.xml.' Key being added: '/visio/comments.xml' "*.

This key is used in '[Content_Types].xml' file, but I don't understand why the library would try to add a new key of that type.

Has anyone ever worked with Aspose and has struck this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cristian Stirbe,
I have tried your scenario in our environment with the latest version 17.8 of Aspose.Diagram for .NET API and managed to replicate the same error. It has been logged under the ticket Id DIAGRAMNET-51353 in our bug tracking system. I will let you know once it is fixed. This is the source Visio drawing and code: [Drawing.vsdx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4k2rqfp2jw12eb/Drawing1.vsdx?dl=0)

[C#]

```
// load Visio drawing
Diagram diagram = new Diagram(dataDir + "Drawing1.vsdx");
// get page by name
Aspose.Diagram.Page page = diagram.Pages.GetPage("Page-1");
// add comment
page.AddComment(7.205905511811023, 3.880708661417323, "test");
// Save drawing
diagram.Save(dataDir + "AddComment_out.vsdx", SaveFileFormat.VSDX);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I would be grateful if you let me know as soon as new news comes up.  Regards ! :)

Comment: @CristianStirbe, the ticket ID DIAGRAMNET-51353 has been resolved . Please download and try the latest version 17.9 of Aspose.Diagram for .NET API: https://downloads.aspose.com/diagram/net/new-releases/aspose.diagram-for-.net-17.9/

Comment: Thank you very much. You have moved so quickly to solve this problem. I will test it and we'll keep in touch if there's something else. Regards.

Comment: After I played a bit with latest version (17.9) of Aspose, I can say the comments looks good now. There also seems to be one more issue: after saving diagram of a file with comments, some attributes are missing in target file. One of them is the edit date and due to its missing, if you open the target file with Aspose, the date of comments will be the default one: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}. I think there is a link between Date-EditDate attributes and it would be nice and useful if the "EditDate" attribute was kept when saving diagram.

Comment: I have already logged this problem under the ticket ID DIAGRAMNET-51357 in our bug tracking system. It has been resolved and our product team has plans to release its fix in the next version 17.10. We will let you know once it is fixed.

Comment: @CristianStirbe, In reference to the ticket ID DIAGRAMNET-51357, please download and try the latest Hotfix version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8yxvbdlaqf69i8/Aspose.Diagram%20for%20.NET%20Hotfix%2017.9.1.zip?dl=0